# WIndows Phone 7 - ListViewItem Class Problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listviewitem

I have an app which was developed using WP7 developer CTP tools.Now I'm trying to run the same app but on WP7 beta tools.

I have made all the changes needed for the above conversion as per [Microsoft Release Notes](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8496c2a-54d9-4b11-9491-a1bfaf32f2e3&displaylang=en#AffinityDownloads)

It has mentioned that **`ListView`** and **`ListViewItem`** classes are removed from **`Microsoft.Phone.Controls`** namespace.

Following is the (modified) XML namespace as per the release notes.

```
xmlns:mpc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

And I have followling line in which ListView is used.

```
<mpc:ListViewItem Layout="TextAndDetailsWithIcon" Text="{Binding Title.Text}" Details="{Binding Title.Text}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneListBoxItemLayout}"/>
```

So (obviously) its giving me error about the namespace issue.
How do I fix it?

---

**UPDATE1** -

I defined the layout of our list item directly in the DataTemplate as

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding Title.Text}" Margin="-2,-13,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
```

Now I'm getting an error about following line which is inside some auto generated file **App.g.cs**

```
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/RssReader;component/App.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

***And the error is***

```
Invalid attribute value mpc:ListViewItem for property TargetType
```

What seems to be the problem now?

(Note : I'm a beginner in Silverlight, So please bear)

Comment: In reference to your update. Search your whole project for "mpc:ListViewItem". Maybe you still have references you need to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does appear that they removed that class according to this [link](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/07/12/migrating-wp7-april-ctp-projects-to-wp7-beta.aspx).

Well, the predefined ListViewItem templates are no more, so instead we define the layout of our list item directly in the DataTemplate, as follows:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="DataTemplateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="ItemImage" Source="/WindowsPhoneListApplication1;component/Images/ArrowImg.png" Height="43" Width="43" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,20,0"/>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding LineOne}" Margin="-2,-13,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="DetailsText" Text="{Binding LineTwo}" Margin="0,-6,0,3" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

When you create a default WindowsPhoneListApplication it also does this layout if you need a full example.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I've got some more problem, though.See the updated question please.

Answer (score 0):

Infact you don't need to define `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`

in

`<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox"  SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">`